# Remove Eclipse package from local git repository and restore to package manager

Tags: eclipse, git, restore

Eclipse Juno & Ubuntu 12.04

About 5 months ago I attempted use git with one of the packages in my project. I had never used git and got quite frustrated when following a tutorial as, pretty quickly, my screen didn't match the tutorial screen shots and some things just didn't work. I got sidetracked for some time with more important work and am now getting back to coding this project. I've also figured out that git is not appropriate for what I'm doing and want to remove my package from the local git repository and restore it to control of the Package Manager. The local git repository is in the workspace.

Here are some (shortened) paths:

```
Package Explorer - before git
 airborne.nodes
   ->/.../development/WorkspaceAirborne/airborne.nodes

Package Explorer - with git
 airborne.nodes [nodes master]
   ->/.../development/hpairborne/nodes/airborne.nodes

Git Repositories
 hpairborne [NO-HEAD]
   ->/.../development/hpairborne/.git

 nodes [master]
   ->/.../development/hpairborne/nodes/.git
```

If I highlight the git repository and right click among the options is "Delete". If I select that, is the code in the repository deleted or does it just remove pointers to it?

How do I proceed to restore the package?